# how to parse 3D array Python

Tags: python, parsing, for-loop, cluster-analysis

My data is 3D array, it looks like this( for each year from 1910-2013, there is array of 51X 200 dimensions, the following is the example of year 1916 for the only the first three rows, e.i 3x200 )

```
Year 1916
AK  0.1216  0.0811  0.0541  0.0405  0.0541  0.0000  0.0473  0.0000  0.0541  0.0000  0.0338  0.0338  0.0473  0.0338  0.0000  0.0405  0.0000  0.0338  0.0338  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0338  0.0000  0.0405  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0405  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0405  0.0338  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0338  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0338  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0338  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  
AL  0.0837  0.0109  0.0113  0.0160  0.0198  0.0158  0.0067  0.0139  0.0121  0.0082  0.0102  0.0083  0.0094  0.0046  0.0031  0.0096  0.0074  0.0164  0.0129  0.0041  0.0042  0.0120  0.0232  0.0100  0.0115  0.0071  0.0024  0.0062  0.0087  0.0095  0.0088  0.0043  0.0078  0.0024  0.0051  0.0375  0.0030  0.0080  0.0101  0.0024  0.0110  0.0064  0.0104  0.0028  0.0019  0.0066  0.0013  0.0052  0.0095  0.0044  0.0048  0.0119  0.0018  0.0081  0.0071  0.0124  0.0044  0.0086  0.0033  0.0022  0.0070  0.0018  0.0025  0.0070  0.0034  0.0075  0.0004  0.0103  0.0008  0.0063  0.0112  0.0006  0.0204  0.0012  0.0022  0.0004  0.0032  0.0025  0.0015  0.0012  0.0073  0.0030  0.0016  0.0045  0.0044  0.0004  0.0028  0.0139  0.0017  0.0026  0.0038  0.0049  0.0167  0.0013  0.0004  0.0009  0.0028  0.0005  0.0050  0.0020  0.0000  0.0033  0.0086  0.0018  0.0012  0.0008  0.0060  0.0035  0.0059  0.0059  0.0008  0.0029  0.0007  0.0052  0.0079  0.0079  0.0028  0.0003  0.0027  0.0066  0.0036  0.0044  0.0032  0.0036  0.0024  0.0000  0.0076  0.0004  0.0068  0.0020  0.0002  0.0004  0.0034  0.0007  0.0011  0.0029  0.0061  0.0003  0.0068  0.0008  0.0066  0.0006  0.0029  0.0004  0.0009  0.0006  0.0036  0.0004  0.0015  0.0007  0.0005  0.0004  0.0019  0.0031  0.0019  0.0060  0.0059  0.0011  0.0000  0.0005  0.0006  0.0016  0.0018  0.0054  0.0014  0.0000  0.0008  0.0010  0.0024  0.0013  0.0040  0.0005  0.0005  0.0004  0.0000  0.0000  0.0037  0.0005  0.0000  0.0015  0.0060  0.0000  0.0000  0.0002  0.0023  0.0000  0.0034  0.0000  0.0000  0.0011  0.0047  0.0002  0.0040  0.0000  0.0018  0.0052  0.0052  0.0004  0.0025  0.0000  
AR  0.0703  0.0193  0.0205  0.0120  0.0232  0.0227  0.0089  0.0110  0.0120  0.0100  0.0082  0.0117  0.0103  0.0061  0.0032  0.0093  0.0113  0.0103  0.0115  0.0040  0.0042  0.0155  0.0245  0.0111  0.0096  0.0065  0.0012  0.0090  0.0155  0.0110  0.0196  0.0059  0.0150  0.0047  0.0042  0.0132  0.0037  0.0087  0.0074  0.0024  0.0079  0.0072  0.0130  0.0026  0.0014  0.0045  0.0018  0.0081  0.0075  0.0045  0.0036  0.0069  0.0009  0.0068  0.0066  0.0095  0.0062  0.0076  0.0042  0.0030  0.0059  0.0022  0.0030  0.0052  0.0068  0.0079  0.0005  0.0094  0.0030  0.0062  0.0076  0.0011  0.0133  0.0017  0.0037  0.0015  0.0048  0.0031  0.0020  0.0010  0.0047  0.0054  0.0024  0.0042  0.0061  0.0018  0.0021  0.0097  0.0032  0.0084  0.0124  0.0047  0.0075  0.0039  0.0000  0.0042  0.0040  0.0008  0.0068  0.0018  0.0000  0.0035  0.0037  0.0030  0.0011  0.0005  0.0047  0.0072  0.0013  0.0048  0.0023  0.0087  0.0008  0.0038  0.0044  0.0045  0.0025  0.0007  0.0033  0.0028  0.0039  0.0024  0.0029  0.0033  0.0030  0.0000  0.0046  0.0011  0.0043  0.0028  0.0006  0.0019  0.0024  0.0009  0.0004  0.0045  0.0035  0.0024  0.0022  0.0007  0.0036  0.0012  0.0025  0.0000  0.0025  0.0005  0.0038  0.0000  0.0019  0.0012  0.0008  0.0017  0.0023  0.0036  0.0023  0.0036  0.0040  0.0005  0.0005  0.0014  0.0005  0.0005  0.0008  0.0044  0.0018  0.0000  0.0005  0.0016  0.0024  0.0030  0.0024  0.0006  0.0000  0.0008  0.0000  0.0000  0.0048  0.0022  0.0000  0.0039  0.0058  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0037  0.0000  0.0022  0.0012  0.0000  0.0012  0.0025  0.0000  0.0061  0.0000  0.0029  0.0023  0.0037  0.0000  0.0032  0.0000
```

My code now parses only one year from a text file that has one year, but I want to parse the data from the text file that has all the years (1910-2013), like doing a loop (for 1 to 103)  and read the data of one year one at a time , and have 103 output when run the code, instead of only one output that I'm having currently in my code. My current code is:

```
def read_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = []
        for line in f:
            data.append([float(x) for x in line.split()[1:]])
        return data #returned the data we read.


def main():
    data = read_from_file("Data_Fcopy.txt") # This data is in scope for the initialize function now. :)


    km = KMeans(n_clusters=9,init= 'random').fit(data)
    print km
    centers = km.cluster_centers_
    labels = km.labels_
    n = km.fit_transform(data)

    print labels
```

Answer (score 0):

You could construct a dict of dicts using an iterator over f:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    data = {}
    i = iter(f)
    try:
        while True:
            year = next(i).split()[-1]
            data[year] = {}
            for _ in range(50):
                row = next(i).split()
                state = row[0]
                data[year][state] = [float(x) for x in row[1:]]
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

Comment: I'm getting: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project1.py", line 20, in <module>
    year = next(i).split()[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: it's not liking this either :  data[year] = {}

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you modify your loop to look for the keyword "year" and then change years when you encounter it:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def read_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        # Defaultdict is nice
        data = defaultdict(list)
        year = None
        for line in f:
            if not line.strip():
                # Empty line, ignore
                continue
            if line.lower().startswith("year"):
                # Data for another year starts here
                year = int(line.split()[1])
            else:
                if not year:
                    # First non-empty row is not "Year ..."
                    raise ValueError("First data has no year")
                # Append the data to the current year
                data[year].append([float(x) for x in line.split()[1:]])
        return data #returned the data we read.

from pprint import pprint
pprint(dict(read_from_file("data")))
```

This input:

```
Year 1916
AK  0.1216  0.0811  0.0541
AL  0.0837  0.0109  0.0113
AR  0.0703  0.0193  0.0205

Year 1917
AK  0.0405  0.0541  0.0000
AL  0.0160  0.0198  0.0158
AR  0.0120  0.0232  0.0227

Year 1918
AK  0.0000  0.0338  0.0338
AL  0.0082  0.0102  0.0083
AR  0.0100  0.0082  0.0117
```

Produces the following:

```
{1916: [[0.1216, 0.0811, 0.0541],
        [0.0837, 0.0109, 0.0113],
        [0.0703, 0.0193, 0.0205]],
 1917: [[0.0405, 0.0541, 0.0],
        [0.016, 0.0198, 0.0158],
        [0.012, 0.0232, 0.0227]],
 1918: [[0.0, 0.0338, 0.0338],
        [0.0082, 0.0102, 0.0083],
        [0.01, 0.0082, 0.0117]]}
```

Comment: I didn't want this output, I want to do a loop to read the data of one year individually, thus read the data 103 times, for each time one different year, and process the rest of the code and have the output of labels for each year, thus in the end there should be output if 103 labels

Comment: How is your data structured? Is it one file containing all years or 103 separate files?

The above code will let you process each year separately by iterating over the keys in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
d=[] <- this is a 1D array(list).
d=[[]] <- this is a 2D array(list).
d=[[[]]] <- this is a 3D array(list).
```

first create an empty  array(list). every time you parse each years file create a 2D array(list) of your data and append it to 3D array(list).
like this.

```
threeD=[]
twoD=[]
oneD=[1,2,3]
twoD.append(oneD)
oneD=[4,5,6]
twoD.append(oneD)
print twoD
# this will output [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

threeD.append(twoD)
print threeD
# this will output [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]]
```

and you can access your 3D array like this threeD[0][0][0]